# Declaring a Variable as a Unique identifier is not working fine

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written a simple SQL query where I declare a variable as an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type, and I am trying to insert that into a table where the column is of `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type. But I get an error message saying

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @SessionId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
SET @SessionId='G51F4E30-E1AB-4E7E-8F5B-0E2613DC9001';

PRINT @SessionId;

INSERT INTO [DB_Name].[dbo].[table_name] ([SessionId])
VALUES (@SessionId);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SET @SessionId='G51F4E30-E1AB-4E7E-8F5B-0E2613DC9001';
                ^
```

'G' is not a valid hexadecimal character. GUIDs can only consist of characters from 0-9 and A-F.